# Use ajax to submit form and receive info from a servlet

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I am developing a webapp using java and currently i need to to send information from a form to a servlet and send feedback back to the html page from the servlet. Specifically when a user connects i want to return from the servlet the username and password of all the users in my database
From what I 've searched the only way to do this properly is by using ajax, but i can't seem to be able to make it work.

**Snippet from html page**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" method="post" action="signIn">
        <input id="uname" name="uname" class="form-control" type="text">
        <input id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" type="password">
        <input id="button1" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    </form>
    <div id=result></div>
```

**My servlet (SingIn.java) currently looks like this**

```
public class SignIn extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

            Registration.setOnline(uname);
            try {
                // loading drivers for mysql
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                // creating connection with the database
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ted", "root", "root");
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from user");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                out.println("<table>");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    uname = rs.getString(1);
                    pass = rs.getString(2);
                    out.println("<tr><th>" + uname +"</th><th>"+ pass + "</th></tr>");
                }
                out.println("</table>");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            RequestDispatcher res = request.getRequestDispatcher("html/index.html");
            res.include(request, response);

    }   
}
```

**Part of my web.xml looks like this**

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SignIn</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/signIn</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As it is i can access the servlet and have the form info submitted, but the servlet's response shows up at the top of the page, whereas i need it to be shown in the "result" div.
I think it's best to use ajax and javascript but i really need help on this part

**Update**
Currently i am trying something like this in ajax
$(document).ready(function() {

```
// Add an event that triggers when the submit
// button is pressed.
$("#button1").click(function() {

    // Get the text from the two inputs.
    var uname = $("#uname").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();



    // Ajax POST request.
    $.post('signIn',{"uname": uname, "pass": pass},
        function() { // on success
            $(#result).innerHTML=(not sure what);
        });

});
```

Comment: where is your Ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript call should look like this:

```
// Ajax POST request.
$.post('./signIn',
    {"uname": uname, "pass": pass},
    function( data ) { // on success
        $( "#result" ).html( data );
    });
```

Or more clearly:

```
// Ajax POST request.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './signIn',
    data: {"uname": uname, "pass": pass},
    success: function( data ) {
        $( "#result" ).html( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: So the above code should remain in the Javascript block?

Comment: Sure. That's the code to tell the browser to make a call to server and update the DOM with the returned result. That's pretty much the whole concept of AJAX.

Comment: Just like that, it did not work. While there is the action="signIn" inside the form tag, the servlet is called and the response is shown at the top of the page. When i remove the action from the form, the ajax works but it messes up my page. Response is not shown where i want it to, page does  not refresh (the modal with the Sign In stays open ) and i get a duplicate of the page just under my normal page. Don't understand this at all

Comment: There are 2 ways: use the form confirmation or AJAX. In the first case the whole page is redirected to the new address, the original content is destroyed and result of your servlet is shown. With AJAX (form is disabled, you did it correctly) you do all the work in JS - you make the background call, get the result and then decide what to do. You can reload the page with `document.location=...;`, or just manipulate DOM (hide login modal, update menu, etc). This is the way single-page applications work - no reloading, just background calls.

Comment: That helped a lot. The problem for the "double" page was in the servlet, i should not have used the res.include(request, response); with the ajax but just the out.println(). Thanks for the help